# How to identify REINSTALL Mode value from MSI Installation log

Tags: windows-installer

I have an verbose mode MSI installation log file.

I want to extract REINSTALLMODE value from the available MSI Installation log file.

How can i identify what REINSTALLMODE value was set while executing MSIEXEC by looking at the verbose MSI installation log ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [small guide on how to read a verbose log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5392761/Advanced%20Installer/Windows_Installer_Log.pdf).